# How to fix dead kernel while executing tensorflow .fit

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, miniconda

The kernel is **dead** while executing `model.fit(train_generator,epochs=20)`, but the same code works on another pc.

This is a juputer log:

Warn 17:03:05: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done

```
at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1204175)
at c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1223227
at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
at v._clearKernelState (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1223212)
at v.dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1216694)
at c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:533674
at t.swallowExceptions (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:913059)
at dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:533652)
at t.RawSession.dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:537330)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
```

Warn 17:03:05: Cell completed with errors [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done

```
at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1204175)
at c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1223227
at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
at v._clearKernelState (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1223212)
at v.dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:1216694)
at c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:533674
at t.swallowExceptions (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:913059)
at dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:533652)
at t.RawSession.dispose (c:\Users\ivanf\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801\out\extension.js:2:537330)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many reasons for kernel to die. But most common reason is memory.

you may reduce your batch size which may help for your computer.

or try to use .py instead of jupyter notebook

refer: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9829

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Cuda drivers to the latest version, and it fixed the problem for me.