# Kernel dies when trying to fit the CNN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conv-neural-network

I am trying the build a CNN model for face recognition using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook. The following versions are used:

```
python==3.7.13
tensorflow==2.6.0
keras==2.6.0
numpy==1.21.5
```

The following code was run to fit the CNN model.

```
classifier.fit(training_set, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=10, validation_data=test_set, validation_steps=10)
```

But the kernel dies giving the message 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically'. Reinstalling numpy & mlk worked once, but not works anymore.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new Python 3.7.13 environment in Anaconda and installing the packages Tensorflow, Keras, Pillow worked!

Answer (score 0):

one of the reason for this issue is your notebook needs more computer power than what actually you have.

**try to reduce your batch size**

or

**try to run everything as python script** which will help you in some cases

refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71768468/14661869

if not try these methods:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892

Comment: I could run the model one without a problem, so I do not think there's a problem with the batch size. Tried, running as a python scrip, but gets an error. The solutions suggested in the git thread also didn't work.